# basic incremental on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to write a simple button that when you click it adds 1 and updates the label but it only works on the first click after that it doesn't update the label anymore

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   }


    protected void ClickerButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {

            Lbl_PairsCooked.Text = CookSneaker(NumOfPairs).ToString();

    }

    public int CookSneaker(int num)
    {
        num += 1;
        return num;
    }
```

The image button i made only works on the first click...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the snippet below on how to get it working. Most importantly you need to read on IsPostBack the link 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.ispostback?view=netframework-4.8 to understand the difference.

```
  public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        int NumOfPairs;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                //this line reads the text from label, converts and assigns to NumPairs. The UI is updated on the button click which takes this new NumOfPairs.
                int.TryParse(Label1.Text, out NumOfPairs);                                
            }
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = CookSneaker(NumOfPairs).ToString();
        }

        public int CookSneaker(int num)
        {
            num += 1;
            return num;
        }

    }
```